# Preserving initial order of the features after filtering in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have some ids as list and I want to filter them in LUCAS dataset. I made a simple example for my problem.

After filtering, I want results as original-initial order of `searchList`. But after filtering, order of features are not in initial order of `searchList`. It is important for me to keep initial orders of features.

How can I solve this?

```
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[26.086635245164302, 41.088934497428085],
      [26.086635245164302, 41.03457263065797],
      [26.14911998637524, 41.03457263065797],
      [26.14911998637524, 41.088934497428085]]], null, false);

var dataset = ee.FeatureCollection("JRC/LUCAS_HARMO/THLOC/V1")
          .filterBounds(geometry)
          //.select('id')

print(dataset)
Map.addLayer(dataset, {}, "LUCAS Points (data)", true);

var searchList = ee.List([950258, 274091, 418881])

var results1 = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.inList('id', searchList))

print(results1)
// results are in order 418881, 950258, 274091

//But results must be in order, 950258, 274091, 418881
```

[Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/75d5d576d401fa490645381cec5fe70e)

Comment: What do you mean by initial order? And why is it important? You can sort into ascending id order with this: `results1.sort("id")`. But I don't know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: My initial order means, order of search list. If result1 contain searchList elements, results must be in initial-original order of features

Answer (score 1):

One idea is to map a function onto your filtered `dataset` that sets as a new property the position of `id` in `sortList`, which can be then used to sort `dataset`:

```
var results1 = dataset.filter(ee.Filter.inList('id', searchList))
  .map(function(feature){
    return feature.set('sortID',searchList.indexOf(feature.get('id')))
    })
  .sort('sortID')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it is working

Comment: There is an explanation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712160/does-javascript-filter-preserve-order, javascript preserves initial order of elements after filtering. Why don't be this in GEE?

Comment: The results are (always) in the same order as they were in the original collection before the filtering.  Your list of IDs is selecting the 1st, 9th and 14th feature from the original collection, and they're coming out in that order.  If you want them in some other order, then, as suggested, you need to sort them into the order you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, Noel